# Convert Numpy vector subtraction to Pytorch tensor subtraction

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to use this code ([from here)](https://github.com/pmocz/nbody-python/blob/master/nbody.py) but in Pytorch (it's an N-body simulation):

```
mass = 20.0*np.ones((500,1))/500  # total mass of particles is 20
pos  = np.random.randn(500,3)
G = 1.0

# positions r = [x,y,z] for all particles
x = pos[:,0:1]
y = pos[:,1:2]
z = pos[:,2:3]

# matrix that stores all pairwise particle separations: r_j - r_i
dx = x.T - x
dy = y.T - y
dz = z.T - z

inv_r3 = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
inv_r3[inv_r3>0] = inv_r3[inv_r3>0]**(-1.5)

ax = G * (dx * inv_r3) @ mass
ay = G * (dy * inv_r3) @ mass
az = G * (dz * inv_r3) @ mass

# pack together the acceleration components
a = np.hstack((ax,ay,az))
```

I know I can break it down per dimension in pytorch:

```
dx = torch.tensor(pos[:,0:1]).T - torch.tensor(pos[:,0:1])
```

The issue is that my tensor is of much larger size than 3 dimension (e.g., `torch.rand(500,1000)` instead of `np.random.randn(500,3)`) so breaking it as done here (e.g., `x = pos[:,0:1]`) is not very practical. Is there a way to have the same code but with a Pytorch tensor of large dimensions without splitting it per dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first deal with the differential terms.

```py
differentials = pos.T[:,None,:] - torch.swapaxes(pos.T[:,None,:], 1, 2)
```

The first part transposes `pos` and adds an extra axis in the middle. Doing that effectively separates the columns from each other. Then, the axis swap does what the transpose did in the 1D array, but only applies it to the desired axes.

You could also save the `pos.T[:,None,:]` to an intermediate variable if you so desire.

For `inv_r3`, that is just summing together the squares of the differentials, which are indexed by axis 0.

```py
inv_r3 = torch.sum(differentials**2, axis=0)
```

The remaining lines are unchanged, though the acceleration terms are already together, it just needs to be squeezed and transposed.

All together:

```py
import torch

N = 500
dims = 3
mass = 20.0*torch.ones((N,1))/N
pos = torch.randn(N,dims)
G = 1.0

differentials = pos.T[:,None,:] - torch.swapaxes(pos.T[:,None,:], 1, 2)
inv_r3 = torch.sum(differentials**2, axis=0)
inv_r3[inv_r3>0] = inv_r3[inv_r3>0]**(-1.5)
acceleration = (G*differentials*inv_r3@mass).squeeze(axis=-1).T
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! Still going through the dimensions here, but can you clarify how the rest of the code would work with this idea? e.g., `inv_r3 = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)` to `a = np.hstack((ax,ay,az))`

Comment: @Penguin Sorry, I read your question too quickly and didn't realize you were looking for everything. I think I have it all covered now. Hopefully, I got all the dimensions right. It can get confusing. It's very easy to end up with something swapped.

Comment: No worries! I'm getting different results when I'm comparing `acceleration` and `a`. Are you getting the same? Am I missing something? Some of the elements in the final tensors are the same so I'm trying to figure out where the issue is. Actually, the `acceleration` tensor seems to have the same elements as `a` but in different locations for some reason

Comment: @Penguin My bad, it shouldn't be a `reshape` but a `squeeze` and transpose. Is it okay now?